# snakemake pipeline automatization

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a .tsv file that looks like this:

```
genome  locus_tag   gene    substrate
PalbDSM11370    02121   susC    pululan
PalbDSM11370    02122   susD    pululan
PalbDSM11370    01210   susC    arabinan
PalbDSM11370    01209   susD    arabinan
PalbDSM11370    02015   susC    bglukan
PalbDSM11370    02016   susD    bglukan
PpalDSM17968    00934   susC    pululan
PpalDSM17968    00933   susD    pululan
PpalDSM17968    02229   susC    arabinan
....
```

I have this rules written:

```
rule extractfeat:
        input:
             '/pathtofile/{genome}.gbk'
        output:
             '{genome}_{locus_tag}_{gene}_{substrate}.fasta'
        shell:
             '''
             extractfeat {input} {output} -type CDS -value {wildcards.genome}_{wildcards.locus_tag} -describe product,locus_tag
             '''

rule transeq:
        input:
             '{genome}_{locus_tag}_{gene}_{substrate}.fasta'
        output:
             'ak_{genome}_{locus_tag}_{gene}_{substrate}'
        shell:
             '''
             transeq {input} {output}
             '''
```

Basically I want to have output of all the rows written in .tsv file.

Thanks!

Comment: Your issue is not very clear to me. What problem do you encounter? What is the role of your .tsv file? Is it to be used to define the possible values of wildcards? Please try to edit your question to clarify the above points. Also, you should probably find a more specific title that will better help people facing similar issues to find your question (and the eventual answers).

Comment: If you want to create output files whose names are based on the lines of your .tsv file, you should probably read this file in python code outside the rules, and construct the list of files to then make it the input of a top "all" rule.